# ASUS SPDIF no sound

Tags: audio, spdif

I have been trying alot to get the digital sound working from my HTPC but without luck.
The setup is as following:

HTPC with ASUS H87M-PRO motherboard which has a SPDIF output using the Realtek ALC892 onboard soundcard.

I am running Windows Server 2012 and the (latest) realtek drivers, version 6.0.1.7071.
SPDIF has been enabled in BIOS and the Realtek HD Audio Manager shows an orange SPDIF port - which I guess indicates that it is enabled.

When I plug in a SPDIF cable it's red in the other end, so something is happening.
As the image also shows the Realtek Digital Output(Optical) is present and sound (from a playing movie) is being output - at least the green indicators moves up and down. http://snag.gy/298hL.jpg

In the receiving end I got a NAD T-775 receiver which supports digital input. I have confirmed this by using a HDMI cable in the same setup. DTS is working just fine through HDMI.
I have made sure that I have selected Optical (and the correct channel) in the receiver.

That sums up the setup I would say - the problem is simple. There is no sound at all through the SDPIF.

I am looking forward to any feedback.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but for a similar setup I don't use the SP/DIF for 5.1, as that forces a double conversion which I find can confuse my amp. I've discovered it's better to just have the PC do a single conversion straight to 5.1 & send that as discrete 6-channel analog to the amp. It also, incidentally, gives me better control over the balance than the amp itself can do.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you’re not using HDMI? It’s vastly superior, after all.

Comment: Yes there is very good reason Daniel B. The thing is that everytime I turn of the NAD receiver the sound through HDMI stops and it will only come back if I have the NAD turned on while I restart the HTPC. This problem also occurs if I change source on the NAD - say change to my Playstation. I guess it's a bug in the Intel HD Graphics driver